# Xamarin.iOS MvvmCross MvxTabBarViewController tabs content inset reset to 0 on tab navigation

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have implemented a MvxTabBarViewController comprising of 3 tabs, each tab's view is a MvxCollectionViewController. The problem I am currently having is that the content inset of the of the MvxCollectionViewController is being set to 0 every time a user navigates between tabs. This is problematic as it does not take the Navigation bar into consideration. I am currently manually setting the the CollectionView.ContentInset in ViewWillAppear of each of the MvxCollectionViewControllers. Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Currently this is what is called in ViewWillAppear:

```
        public void SetViewLayer()
        {
            CollectionView.ContentOffset = new PointF (0f, -64f);

            AdjustInsetsForNavigationBar (new UIEdgeInsets (64f, 0f, 64f, 0f));
        }

        public virtual void AdjustInsetsForNavigationBar (UIEdgeInsets insets)
        {
            CollectionView.ContentInset = insets;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am currently only experiencing this when running the app on an iPad, the iPhone version works as expected.

Comment: Are you using any kind of custom presenters? If so, you might be able to move this logic into that place. Would make it a bit cleaner